# Remove special characters with using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

guys. I have specific string with a lot of special characters which I need to remove.

Here is the string:

```
let str = 'The start tag must have a matching end tag.  An explicit end tag can be provided by adding &lt;/cfscript&gt;.If the body of the tag is empty, you can use the shortcut &lt;cfscript .../&gt;.&lt;p&gt;The CFML compiler was processing:&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;A cfscript tag beginning on line 90, column 10.&lt;li&gt;A cfscript tag beginning on line 90, column 10.&lt;/ul&gt;'
```

Here is  my regex which does not work :
`var regex =  str.replace(/&lt;|&gt;|\/|\/ul|\/li|ul&|li&/g,'')`

Any help would be great! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to strip escaped HTML tags (< is `&lt`; and > is `&gt;`), and everything between a pair of them (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/o4ZDhL/1)):

```js
const str = 'The start tag must have a matching end tag.  An explicit end tag can be provided by adding &lt;/cfscript&gt;.If the body of the tag is empty, you can use the shortcut &lt;cfscript .../&gt;.&lt;p&gt;The CFML compiler was processing:&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;A cfscript tag beginning on line 90, column 10.&lt;li&gt;A cfscript tag beginning on line 90, column 10.&lt;/ul&gt;'

const result = str.replace(/&lt;.+?&gt;/g,'')

console.log(result)
```